# Feature Branch Workflow Tool

Tags: git, git-flow

Is there an extension for git, like [GitFlow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) but uses the [Feature Branch Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!workflow-feature-branch), meaning:

- master
- feature branches
- pull requests to master

Comment: ... What about git? That might seem snide, but I'm being quite serious. Git does this, with *extremely* simple commands. I'm not sure why you'd need a tool or extension for this.

Answer (score 1):

There are [**`git-extras`**](https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras), a collection of wrapper commands for git. You could have a look at [`pull-request`](https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras/blob/master/bin/git-pull-request), which creates a `PR` on GitHub (if you use GitLab instead, check their [`API`](http://api.gitlab.org/merge_requests.html) to port this).

Some other interesting commands (not adding much to vanilla git though):

- [`git-create-branch`](https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras/blob/master/bin/git-create-branch): Create, pull and track a new remote (feature) branch.
- [`git-delete-merged-branches`](https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras/blob/master/bin/git-delete-merged-branches): E. g. to clean up after merging a feature branch.

Also there is [**`hub`**](https://github.com/github/hub), having a similar command `git pull-request` that create a `PR` for the current feature branch.

I think, these are not really what you want, but – depending on what platform you use for pull requests – you could combine some commands in a suite that comes quite close and support your workflow.